# Get the most letters in a string PHP

Tags: php

I Need PHP Function that can get the most letters from the string

```
$string = "111010111010001101";
$execute = SomeFunction($string);
echo $execute;
```

and the ouput will be like this

```
1
```

is there a php function like that? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```
$string = "111010111010001101";

//$string = "abaacabdeeeee";

$array_count = array_count_values(str_split($string));
$res = array_keys($array_count, max($array_count));

print_r($res);
```

To make it a function, just do this:

```
function SomeFunction($string){
   $array_count = array_count_values(str_split($string));
   return array_keys($array_count, max($array_count));
}

print_r(SomeFunction('111010111010001101'));
```

Output

```
 1 //or e in the commented one I tested
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3b238c83c236c80d2f794d98dc32e0eb27c9b2bb)

**How it works**:

- Split the string into an array of chars `str_split`
- count the occurrences of the chars `array_count_values`
- get the key with the max number of occurrences `array_keys` and `max`

**Caveats**:

If two values are equal then they will both be returned in the result.  For example

```
$string = 'ababababcd';
```

Output

```
Array
(
   [0] => a
   [1] => b
)
```

You never mentioned what you want to happen in this case (a tie).  For your particular case that may not even be an issue.  But I had to mention it for the sake of completeness.  If you don't want the return as an array you can do something like this (to return false or the first element):

```
function SomeFunction($string){
   $array_count = array_count_values(str_split($string));
   $res = array_keys($array_count, max($array_count));
   if(empty($res)) return false;
   return array_shift($res);
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Not effective but simple

```
max(str_split($string));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, so long as your character set isn't a multibyte one with multibyte characters in the string.  See the manual page for [count_chars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php)